# Onchange event not calling when uploading same file in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

1. onchange event not calling when uploading same file in safari
   browser, while after uploading each file i am setting field as a
   blank and then trying to upload same file. But onchange event not
   calling in safari browser while it working fine in remaining
   browser, Any one can please help me why this happening.

Comment: Can you please add some code here so that we can analyse what's wrong?

Comment: @Akshay <input  ng-model-instant type="file"  multiple onchange='myFunction()'  /> function myFunction{ alert('here');} myFuction not getting any alert here

Comment: Please edit the question and post your code there. Please add the HTML, Javascript as well.

Comment: I have a long code of my project which contain angularjs directive and model etc, which is not possible to share here, So please simply share your ideas that I can guess something ahead

Comment: How are we supposed to help when we have no clue as to what file uploader you are using or is it a custom code that you wrote? What your/library Code does?